# Migration fails after I separated the projects

Tags: c#, .net

Before I separated my application into other projects, everything related to my Models, Database was inside BulkyBookWeb, and after the projects were separated, it looked like this

```
BulkyBook
/ BulkyBook.DataAccess
/ BulkyBook.Models
/ BulkyBook.Utility
/ BulkyBookWeb
```

Inside BulkyBook.DataAccess contains my ApplicationDbContext, my migrations and also the repository.
And inside BulkyBook.Models contains my representation of the model.

And when running the command `BulkyBookWeb git:(main) ✗ dotnet ef migrations add AddCoverTypeToDatabase`

```
Your target project 'BulkyBookWeb' doesn't match your migrations assembly 'BulkyBook.DataAccess'. Either change your target project or change your migrations assembly.
Change your migrations assembly by using DbContextOptionsBuilder. E.g. options.UseSqlServer(connection, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("BulkyBookWeb")). By default, the migrations assembly is the assembly containing the DbContext.
Change your target project to the migrations project by using the Package Manager Console's Default project drop-down list, or by executing "dotnet ef" from the directory containing the migrations project.
```

At BulkyBookWeb at Program.cs I put

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppDbContext"), option => option.MigrationsAssembly("BulkyBookWeb")
));
```

But the folder Migration was created inside of the BulkyBookWeb, but I want the migration create inside of BulkyBook.DataAccess inside of Migrations folder using the Model inside of BulkyBook.Models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. At `Program.cs` at BulkyBookWeb I needed to put this line pointing to my other project that contains the migrations.

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 
    options.UseSqlServer(
        builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppDbContext"), 
        option => option.MigrationsAssembly("BulkyBook.DataAccess")
    )
);
```